# How to print the matching regex input only?

Tags: shell

I have the following input in a file

```
{ 1=[2,5,6,7], 23=[21, 9, 44], 345=[7,7,7,7], 3456=[0], 56789=[66, 77], 42=[678, 110, 112] }
```

I want to print the number before equals and that number can be anywhere between 1 to 5 digits.

```
Required output
---------------
1
23
345
3456
56789
42
```

restriction I have is I Cannot use any perl expression.

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -Eo "[0-9]{1,5}=" /path/to/file | sed 's/.$//'
```